# Central and inscribed angles

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

We know that the inscribed angle is half of the central angle. But, I believe that there are other points inside the circle (the point(s) B in the figure below other than the origin of the circle), such that: $\beta= \frac{1}{2}\alpha$.
[image: Central and Inscribed angles]

I tried using geogebra to change the position of point B (without changing the points A, C, and D) in such a way the relation above holds but I cannot prove it.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As you move from $A$ to $B$ it seems the angle increases continuously from $\beta$ to $\alpha$. So all the angles interior to the circle should measure greater than $\beta$

Comment: Yes I tried that. But what if we move **only** the point B?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. Are you asking to prove that in general, there exists a point $B$, inside triangle $ADC$ such that the $\beta = \frac{\alpha}{2}$?

Comment: @Dashi : Actually, I think there are many points inside the circle not necessarily inside the triangle ADC (I am not sure about the exact locations)

Comment: Oh my bad for some weird reason I thought B was the center. Let me think again..

Comment: So then are you just asking to prove the existence of a point? or are you suggesting there could be infinitely many points, and are asking for proof of that?

Comment: If you move $A$ anywhere along the larger arc, the angle $\beta$ remains fixed. Similarly, there’s at least a circular arc along which you can move $B$ while keeping $\alpha$ fixed.

Comment: @Dashi: I don't know how many points there, If one can find an elegant mathematical way to describe that will be awesome.

Comment: @amd that's a great insight, but how can we prove that it is actually an arc?

Comment: You can prove that easily by constructing a circle that passes through the points B, C, D

Comment: It’s a straightforward consequence of the inscribed angle theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Denote $O$ to be the center, and draw a circle passing through $C,D,O$ (which is always possible given there are only 3 points).  Then, if you "slide" $O$ along the arc, you will still get $\angle CBD=\alpha$.

(As in the diagram, $\angle CBD=\angle COD$):

[image]